# What is the correct punctuation for this whimsical sign I bought?

Tags: punctuation

The sign reads "Beer, the reason I wake up every afternoon". In order to be humorous and not pitiful doesn't it need a pause after the "up"? Comma or period or semi-colon? Thanks

Comment: The punctuation is fine as it is. The sign is humorous - there is no "pity" involved.

Comment: I reckon the humour lies in the potential for inducing pity in the beholder, and *that* is entirely intentional.

Comment: Fine as is, but if I wanted to heighten the hangover point: *Beer: the reason I wake up ... every afternoon*

Comment: Personally, I would use a colon or a dash after *beer* rather than the comma.

Comment: The humor in this statement comes from the unexpected turnaround between "wake up" (usually associated with the morning) and "every afternoon." There is no pity implied, but the surprise at the end of the statement fills in the picture and tells us something about the speaker. (BTW, the punctuation in the original is fine.)